# Why can't angular interpolate value anymore?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I am using the latest angular with the following code (it used to work before) and the ng-init crash with error:

```
<tbody ng-controller="MyCtrl" id={{ row.id }} ng-init="init('{{ row.id }}', {$ config.stats $})">
```

Where as {{ }}  is the template render in Django and the {$ $} is the interpolate symbol in angular (I know it is a bit strange but the it requires the backend and frontend data.

When I render the page, I got the following error:

```
Token 'config' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 65 of the expression [init('row__e3ff11c0-bd6b-47e2-8ed8- ... starting at [config.stats $})].
```

It used to work before but looks like the latest angular doesn't take it.

Just wonder how can I fix it so that I can pass the config.stats inside the init function. config.stats is a JSON object.

Comment: Why don't you move that initialization code inside your controller. ngInit is really only appropriate for aliasing

Comment: Angular template is `{{something}}` I never saw `{$`, and you need to double quotes also this `id="{{ row.id }}"` and finally in the ng-init you don't need to insert templating, just the variable.

Comment: I wonder if we're running into a similar issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339430/angularjs-accessing-an-element-directives-attributes-from-within-a-controller

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the `ng-init` where you don't need to interpolate with `{$$}`:

```
ng-init="init('{{ row.id }}', config.stats)"
```

You still need the `{{}}` interpolation for django.