# AngularJS: Accessing an element directive's attributes from within a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Problem**: The attribute I pass to my directive's controller is not evaluated. For example, I get `{{ attribute.value }}` instead of `5`.

**Desired Outcome**: My directive's controller has access to a primary key contained in an object from a parent controller. I need it to make API calls like `MyResource.save({id: attribute});`.

**Code Snippets**:

*Calling directive from HTML*

```
<div ng-controller="BoatDetailController as boatCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <booking-widget boat-id="{{ boatCtrl.boat.id }}"></booking-widget>
  </div>
```

*Directive*

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.
        module('trips').
        directive('bookingWidget', bookingWidget);

    bookingWidget.$inject = [];

    function bookingWidget() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                boatId: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: "/static/app/trips/trips.bookingwidget.template.html",
            controller: 'BookingWidgetController as bookingCtrl'
        }
    }
})();
```

*Controller*

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.
        module('trips').
        controller('BookingWidgetController', BookingWidgetController);

    BookingWidgetController.$inject = ['Trip', 'Booking', 'Messages', '$scope', '$attrs'];

    function BookingWidgetController(Trip, Booking, Messages, $scope, $attrs) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.boatId = $attrs.boatId;
        ...

        activate();

        //////////////////////////////

        function activate() {
            console.log(vm.boatId);
            //
        }
```

**Console Results**:

With `$scope.boatId`:  (logs a blank line)

With `$attrs.boatId`: `{{ boatCtrl.boat.id }}` (a string)

**Recap**: The `boat-id` attribute of my directive is not resolving. Can you help me figure out how to fix it?

Comment: hey, did you try accessing the attributes and their values in the link function of the directive?

Comment: I haven't! To be honest, I'm not sure how... I'm very confused about this, though. There is (on the same project) a working directive with this same structure. The only difference is that (in this case) I need to use the attribute in the controller instead of the template. How would you go about accessing the attribute in a `link` function then accessing it from the controller?

Comment: I have successfully logged the value to the console using `attrs.$observe` in a link function. Any ideas on how to get this to the controller? Could I use `bookingCtrl.boatId = value;`?

Comment: you have the scope available in link function. You can store in on the scope object in link function, and access the same in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually create a custom directive like this:

```
function bookingWidget() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                boatId: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: "/static/app/trips/trips.bookingwidget.template.html",
            controller: 'BookingWidgetController as bookingCtrl',
            link : function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
               console.log(attrs.boatId);
               scope.boatId = attrs.boatId;
            }
        }
    }
```

The link function actually allows you to have an access to the element, the scope of the directive, the attributes associated to the directive and the controller of the directive. The function is called after everything associated to the directive has been performed. In other words, this is the last stage.

The same scope would be shareable between the link function and controller.

Now, to make the API call, you may actually add a function in your controller that accepts the boatID, makes a call to the API and accepts the response onto the controller object. After that, add a watcher within the link function that watches over "vm.boatId", within which you may call that function which makes the API call. So, even if the controller has initialized before the link function, you would still be able to perform what you wish to. So, it would be a "link-based activation".

You may give this solution a try. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm so close to understanding, but not quite there. In the controller, how would I call the value? `$scope.boatId` still logs a blank line.

Comment: @PANDAStack: within the link function, are you able to get the value of scope.boatId? If so, then, you must be having scope.bookingCtrl available within the link function. You can assign scope.bookingCtrl.boatId = attrs.boatId.

Comment: Yes. Within `link` I can log `45` for example, the correct boat primary key. I will continue to try to find a way to access within the controller.

Comment: @PANDAStack: can you check whether you have the  scope.bookingCtrl available within the link function?

Comment: I do have it. And in fact, it shows that I have correctly passed `boatId` into the controller. I think the issue might be that `link` runs last. The `controller` function runs first. So by the time `link` has had a chance to assign a value, code within `controller` will already be running.

Comment: By using this code, I am able to assign the value within the controller to the place I need it. It seems somewhat un-Angular to do this, but it's the only way I have found it to work. `$scope.$watch(function () {
                return vm.boatId;
            },
            function () {
                vm.booking.data.boat = vm.boatId;
            }, true);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93337/discussion-between-shivi-and-panda-stack).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function and call it. Need to use **&** then.

https://thinkster.io/egghead/isolate-scope-am